# How to avoid duplicate SQL data while executing the INSERT queries without source database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got the 2 bulk data by insert the data into SQL Server database by SQL Server queries from multiple different source (multiple `.sdf` files (SQL CE database)) from the clients. But I have the queries of with more then 1000's records with multiple `.sdf` files.

When I execute the 2nd SQL queries scripts file (ex. data 2nd `.sdf` file) then I have got the duplicate data error occur.

How can I protect the data from duplicate records while executing the data. I cannot amend the queries like `join` or `select` manually by copy paste as more than 1000's of record with multiple table.

Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO [Patients] ([PatientGuid],[FirstName],[LastName],[PatientID],[DateOfBirth],[Gender],[Comment],[HighLimit],[LowLimit],[HighLimitNova],[LowLimitNova],[Disabled],[PhysicianGuid],[CF1],[CF2],[CF3],[CF4],[CF5],[ShowLimits],[ShowLimitsNova]) VALUES (
'9192596b-8fbb-4f6f-8412-0082fa2af40d',N'Sonia Isabel',N'Pereira Nunes Santos',N'174269',{ts '1976-01-25 00:00:00.000'},1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO [Patients] ([PatientGuid],[FirstName],[LastName],[PatientID],[DateOfBirth],[Gender],[Comment],[HighLimit],[LowLimit],[HighLimitNova],[LowLimitNova],[Disabled],[PhysicianGuid],[CF1],[CF2],[CF3],[CF4],[CF5],[ShowLimits],[ShowLimitsNova]) VALUES (
'd3f7fa12-6ba4-4fcb-9847-00b26bbff040',N'Antonio José',N'Maia Machado',N'31145',{ts '1957-03-15 00:00:00.000'},2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO [Patients] ([PatientGuid],[FirstName],[LastName],[PatientID],[DateOfBirth],[Gender],[Comment],[HighLimit],[LowLimit],[HighLimitNova],[LowLimitNova],[Disabled],[PhysicianGuid],[CF1],[CF2],[CF3],[CF4],[CF5],[ShowLimits],[ShowLimitsNova]) VALUES (
'f716ea62-0eb6-427e-836d-00e6f82ac01e',N'Hans Rudolf',N'Küng',N'205934',{ts '1944-04-03 00:00:00.000'},2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
GO
```

Thanks

ST

Comment: The sample has no duplicates

Comment: Load the data and remove the duplicates after the data is in the database.

Comment: The typical way to import external data is to store it into staging tables first, clean it up and load the cleaned data into the production tables.

Comment: HI I can load the bulk data by 1st script (from 1st .sdf file) into SQL Server database. When I load the data from 2nd sql scripts then I face the duplicate errors. I only have the sql scripts by the customer vendor. I can not copy individuals GUIDs from the source scripts because another table have multiple GUIDs.

Answer (score 1):

Only execute `INSERT` if not exists on table

```
IF not exists(select * from [Patients] where [PatienGuid] = '9192596b-8fbb-4f6f-8412-0082fa2af40d')
    INSERT INTO [Patients] ([PatienGuid],[FirstName],[LastName],[PatientID],[DateOfBirth],[Gender],[Comment],[HighLimit],[LowLimit],[HighLimitNova],[LowLimitNova],[Disabled],[PhysicianGuid],[CF1],[CF2],[CF3],[CF4],[CF5],[ShowLimits],[ShowLimitsNova]) 
        VALUES ('9192596b-8fbb-4f6f-8412-0082fa2af40d',N'Sonia Isabel',N'Pereira Nunes Santos',N'174269',{ts '1976-01-25 00:00:00.000'},1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my SQL Server Compact Bulk Copy library, SqlCeBulkCopy, it has an option to ignore duplicate primary key errors. It is available on NuGet.org